# "Unable to find suitable address" when trying to mount Azure File storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Basically I created a file storage account in Azure, with the settings allowing any network to mount this storage.

When I go to my VM (in Azure as well) and I run the following command (redacted)

```
sudo mount -t cifs //redacted.file.core.windows.net/redacted-media /mnt/redacted-media/ -o vers=3.0,username=redacted,password=redacted,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp
```

I get the error `Unable to find suitable address`. I already opened ports 445 and 139 in the network settings for the VM but still no luck.

The logs errors are the following:

`Feb 11 13:26:25 redacted kernel: Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=40.116.232.108 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4094 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57282 DPT=445 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Feb 11 13:26:27 redacted kernel: Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=40.116.232.108 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4095 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57282 DPT=445 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Feb 11 13:26:27 redacted kernel: Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=40.116.232.108 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=46253 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50176 DPT=139 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to mount the file share in Azure storage account to your Azure Linux VM, you could follow this DOC: [Use Azure Files with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux). In your case, the problem probably is your password which should be a storage account key. You could find it from storage account--settings---Access keys---select Key1 or Key2. Also, default the Azure VM outbound traffic has no restriction on port 445. You should ensure that the outbound traffic from Azure VM to your storage account is not blocking port 445.

The detailed steps:

1. For a connection in other Azure regions, differ from your storage account, you must use SMB 3.0, SMB 3.0 encryption support was introduced in Linux kernel version 4.11.
2. The cifs-utils package is installed. For example, you could run this on Ubuntu.
   `sudo apt-get update`  `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`
3. Decide on the directory/file permissions of the mounted share. In the examples below, permission 0777 is used to give read, write, and execute permissions to all users.
4. Ensure port 445 is open: SMB communicates over TCP port 445 - check to see if your firewall is not blocking TCP ports 445 from the client.

Remember to replace **storage-account-name**, **share-name**, **smb-version**, **storage-account-key**, and **mount-point** with the appropriate information for your environment. This works on my side, I use Linux Ubuntu 4.15.0-1036.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/fileshare  /mnt/MyAzureFileShare -o vers=3.0,username=storageaccountname,password=xxxstorageaccountkeyxxx,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: My VM has the port 445 open on any protocol, from any port. With the same command provided in the Azure connect section I can mount this file storage in a different VM, but not on this one.

Comment: Both VM are in the same subnet or region or os? Is there any firewall inside the VM? Both VM support SMB 3.0?

Comment: Yes, both VM and Storage account are in the same region and subnet, I even added the public IP from the VM but no luck. Yes, both VMs support SMB 3, I tried to mount with SMB 2.1 but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you run `sudo telnet storagaccount.file.core.windows.net 445` to verify the network connectivity on the problematic VM? Probably, the system firewall inside the VM is blocking the outbound 445. Could you verify this on your side like `sudo ufw status` or `sudo iptables -L` on Ubuntu?  More [references](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/introduction-to-iptables/).

Comment: Thanks for following up, I can see that by using telnet I get "Connection refused". It's also strange than when doing `sudo iptables -L` I can see lots of rules being applied, I'm not sure where these are coming from, `/etc/sysconfig/` doesn't have any file with saved rules.

Comment: Iptables is a firewall, installed by default on all official Ubuntu distributions. But it allows all traffic by default. I guess you have misconfigured your firewall inside the VM before. You could temporarily disable firewall by  `sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` or `sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` to verify this on your side. More details about iptables from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo?action=show&redirect=Iptables).

Comment: It's been a struggle, a couple days ago I flushed the iptables rules to make sure nothing was blocking the storage, but now the VM became unresponsive, it boots fine but the VM Linux agent is unresponsive, can't ssh into it or from any other VM within the subnet. I reset ssh configuration, reset the network interface, changed the IP, switched to a different interface, removed it from the security group. Nothing has worked, I'll have to file a ticket with Azure.

Comment: I think the issue seems to be caused by the VM internal firewall, I'm still working on it since this VM has multiple rules that I need to move to the Azure firewall instead.

Comment: Me too, if the issue has been fixed or you need any help, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to finally mount it, just adding an extra output rule to allow 445 on TCP. But definitely will disable the firewall from within the VM and let Azure control the networking rules, having 2 firewalls is a pain.